# Keeping selected value in drop down menu PHP HTML

Tags: php, html

I have the below code but every time I pick a value and the page refreshes the values inside the drop down menu revert back to default, how Can I keep the selected values.

I can not use AJAX as the user does not want that.

I did search online and found out that I need to add "selected" but when I do that on the while statement it does not work.

here is the code I have used so far

```
<h4>Please select a Scheme name</h4>
<br>
<form name="export_form" action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
  <select name="schemaNameSelect" id='schema_name_dropdown_menu'>

    <option value='default' id='default' >Please select scheme name</option>
    <option value='ViewAll' id='ViewAll' >View All</option></center>

    <?php
    while($dbRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($dbQuery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo "<option value='".$dbRow[Schema_Name]."'>". $dbRow[Schema_Name] . " </option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";
  }
  ?>
  <a  id="viewButton" type="submit"><button id="viewBtn">View</button></a>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_docs" value="Export your certificate" id="exportBtn" class="input-button" />

  <div id="test">
    <br/>
    <input id="create_schema_wrapper_input" name="schemaNameTextbox" data-id="12" class="stage3-input" placeholder="Please insert new schema name here">
  </div>

</form>



<form name="export_form" action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">

</form>
<table class="table table-striped" id="student">
  <tr>
    <th>Schema Name</th><th>Stakeholder</th><th>Stakeholder Return</th><th>Schema Return</th>
  </tr>

  <?php 
  if (isset($_POST['schemaNameSelect'])) {
    $schemaName = $_POST['schemaNameSelect'];
    databaseOutput($schemaName); 
  } else {
    databaseOutput("ViewAll"); 
  }
  ?>
</table>
</body>

<style>
#schema_name_dropdown_menu{
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#test{
  display: none;
}
#viewButton{
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: none;
}

#viewButton:hover {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#viewBtn{
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px; 
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#exportBtn{
  margin: 5px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#schema_name_dropdown_menu').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'default')
    {
      $('#viewButton').hide();
    }else{
      $('#viewButton').show();
      $('#test').hide();
      var value = $("#schema_name_dropdown_menu option:selected").val();
      $('#test').text(value);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: _“but when I do that on the while statement it does not work”_ - well then you did it _wrong_, so _show us_ what you tried.

Comment: <option value='default' id='default' selected>Please select scheme name</option>
<option value='ViewAll' id='ViewAll' selected>View All</option></center> Those two are okay, but I dont know where to put the selected here ( echo "<option value='".$dbRow[Schema_Name]."'>". $dbRow[Schema_Name] . " </option>";) so it wont loop to the last results

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code there, in comments this is hardly readable. And you obviously need an `if` statement or something similar inside your loop, to determine whether the current option you are about to output is the one that needs to get `selected` set or not.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that I am new to php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop that fills the dropdown, check if the dropdown has been selected and then add the `selected` attribute to the option as it is found in the while loop

```
<h4>Please select a Scheme name</h4>
<br>
<form name="export_form" action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
  <select name="schemaNameSelect" id='schema_name_dropdown_menu'>

    <option value='default' id='default' >Please select scheme name</option>
    <option value='ViewAll' id='ViewAll' >View All</option></center>

    <?php
    while($dbRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($dbQuery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        // code to add the selected attribute
        $sel = '';
        if (    isset($_POST['schemaNameSelect']) 
            &&  $_POST['schemaNameSelect'] == $dbRow[Schema_Name] ) 
        {
            $sel = 'selected';
        }


        echo "<option $sel value='".$dbRow[Schema_Name]."'>". $dbRow[Schema_Name] . " </option>";
        // change     ^^^
    }

    echo "</select>";
  }
  ?>
  <a  id="viewButton" type="submit"><button id="viewBtn">View</button></a>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_docs" value="Export your certificate" id="exportBtn" class="input-button" />

  <div id="test">
    <br/>
    <input id="create_schema_wrapper_input" name="schemaNameTextbox" data-id="12" class="stage3-input" placeholder="Please insert new schema name here">
  </div>

</form>



<form name="export_form" action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">

</form>
<table class="table table-striped" id="student">
  <tr>
    <th>Schema Name</th><th>Stakeholder</th><th>Stakeholder Return</th><th>Schema Return</th>
  </tr>

  <?php 
  if (isset($_POST['schemaNameSelect'])) {
    $schemaName = $_POST['schemaNameSelect'];
    databaseOutput($schemaName); 
  } else {
    databaseOutput("ViewAll"); 
  }
  ?>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello I did the above code and I got a blank page, do I meant to put something inside  $sel = '';???

Comment: I am sorry I am new to php thats why

Comment: @Faz887766 Make sure you add a closing PHP tag `?>`

Comment: @proit I did and it still got the blank screen I really dont understand why as the code is perfectly fine

Comment: $sel = 'selected'; is that predefined?

Comment: @Faz887766 No but it does not need to be. Its initialized to nothing before the IF

Comment: @riggsfolly I dont understand why it is blank

Comment: Each time round the loop it will be set to `''` so it will only contain `'seleted'` for the one line that should be selected

Comment: still same issue :( do I need to put selected on here <option value='default' id='default' >Please select scheme name</option>

Comment: This code is a small addition to your EXISTING code i.e. the WHILE loop inside the `<form name=export_form" ....` section of your script

Comment: Are you putting this code in the right place in your script?

Comment: Yes I am, https://pastebin.com/embed_js/xkzRUv2L here is the whole code, I added it to line 260 where it should be

Comment: no more blank pages, however, when I use to select a value a button with "view" used to come up now that button no longer comes up

Comment: can you check the script 341 maybe its something to do with that please

Comment: Ok I added the code into your existing code insitu so it shoudl now be obvious where to put it

Comment: what do you mean by change ^^^ do I need to change anything there or just copy paste thanks so much for your help and for being so patient

Comment: I dont know if you could help me please but I would like to give a warning when a user picks "please select a schema" from the drop down menu I have wrote the code but I am not sure where to put it please. the warning to say please select a schema

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select name="select">
        <option <?=$variable1 == $variable2 ? 'selected' : ''?> value="1">One</option>
    </select>
```